# Removing all installed Gems and starting over

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I recently started learning Ruby and Ruby on Rails, and have watched a plethora of getting started materials.  I have been finding lately that I keep getting errors where gems won't install or they will be installed but they can't be used for some reason, and I have decided that I want to remove everything down to once again just having Ruby installed and start over with the installation.  One training video had me install most of my gems with RVM, so I don't know if that changes anything.

So in short my question is "How to I get rid of RVM, Rubygems, and all installed Gems so that I can start over with just Ruby?"

**Edit: I am on Mac OS 10.6**

Comment: Did you install into /opt/ruby? Thats what I do so I can remove ruby fast.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100496/uninstalling-all-gems-ruby-2-0-0/15100497#15100497

This should work for 1.9.3 as well :)

Comment: Your question's title and "short question" summary at the end are two different things...

Answer (score 140, accepted):

From the [RVM](https://rvm.io/support/faq) support site:

> RVM installs everything into ~/.rvm.
>   To remove RVM from your system run 'rm
>   -rf ~/.rvm'. You may have one additional config file in ~/.rvmrc and
>   of course the RVM hook in your
>   bash/zsh startup files.

So, just go to the command line and type `rm -rf ~/.rvm`

All the installed gems are in the ~/.rvm folders, so doing the above will remove the gems and installed rubies in one go.

Gems you added pre-RVM with the default ruby install can be removed by typing this at the command prompt:

```
for x in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall $x -a -x -I; done
```

Comment: I just ran that, but gems is still installed.  It does however look like it reloaded it.  Not sure if it reloaded with defaults from Mac XCode or what...

Comment: added another line to get rid of the gems you added pre-RVM

Comment: I'd add the '-all -x -I' options to gem uninstall to prevent it from prompting you (for binaries, versions, or dependencies) while uninstalling.

Comment: For reference, the full command is: for x in \`gem list --no-versions\`; do gem uninstall $x -a -x -I; done

Comment: For more reference, another option: `gem list --no-versions | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`

Comment: This actually works quite nicely with rbenv as well on Debian

Comment: doing this gave me the following error once i ran it and ran bundle install:
``` ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/bin/bundle: No such file or directory```

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.rvm` into `bundle install` worked for me. Bundler was constantly trying to access the gems of the older ruby versions

Answer (score 187):

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

Uninstalls all gems without prompt.

#### Options

```
-a, --[no-]all                   Uninstall all matching versions
-I, --[no-]ignore-dependencies   Ignore dependency requirements while
                                 uninstalling
-x, --[no-]executables           Uninstall applicable executables without
                                 confirmation
```

Comment: That gives me: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
gist is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
gem uninstall -i /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all gist`

Comment: then you should do as it suggest. then after that, rerun `gem uninstall -aIx` again. repeat if error occured for other gem untill it finisehd

Comment: That's what I did, I had to repeat those steps a few dozen times.
Sometimes, the `gem` was complaining that I didn't have the right permissions for a directory:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0/bin directory.
`

In fact, the directory didn't exist: I just had to `mkdir` it and re-run the `gem` command.

Comment: So `gem uninstall --all --ignore-dependencies --executables`

Answer (score 35):

For **Windows** and **Unix** copy/paste in command prompt (**Ruby 1.9.x**).

```
ruby -e "`gem list`.split(/$/).each { |line| puts `gem uninstall -Iax #{line.split(' ')[0]}` unless line.strip.empty? }"
```

Comment: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
-e:1: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
bundle (0.0.1)
            ^
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
bundle (0.0.1)
             ^
`

Comment: @isomorphismes not sure if I have fixed it, but you can try command now.

Answer (score 29):

using RVM, you could just type...

```
rvm gemset empty GEMSET
```

where GEMSET is the gemset which you would like to empty. then...

install bundle

`yum install bundler` and finally

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 18):

`rvm implode` (see [cli docs](http://rvm.io/rvm/cli)) seems to work - and it even tells you where to look at for leftovers

Comment: This is technically the most correct answer and exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: "implode   - removes all ruby installations it manages, everything in ~/.rvm"

Comment: "implode does not uninstall the RVM itself. Basically, there is no way to automatically uninstall RVM other than manually cleaning up everything that the installation did to your system. And that’s a huge downside.

The only way to uninstall RVM is to manually clean up everything it did to your system."

source: https://duseev.com/articles/rbenv-vs-rvm/     

NOTE: I'm a novice and unqualified to determine whether the advice in the article is accurate.

Comment: @MarkGavagan I agree it does not do everything, but it will tell you what else needs to be done (what I refer to above as "leftovers"). In fact, that very article's step zero on uninstalling rvm is... `rvm impode` :-)

Comment: Does this have the same effect as `rvm gemset empty GEMSET`?

Comment: @Beyar I'm not super familiar with `rvm gemset`, but I think it won't remove the rvm tooling (including the `rvm` utility itself), nor the extra files that `rvm implode` will inform you about.

Answer (score 7):

1. This is work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.  For me, when I was executing
   command rails -v it throw errors because of NameError. I have
   installed 3 version of rails (4.2.0, 4.2.6, 5.0.0.1). I was trying
   to uninstall unnecessary gem using command ***gem uninstall rails -v
   version number*** but I won't able to, but I find a way to solve
   this problem. In order to uninstall all gems, you have to loop
   through all entries in gem list with bash scripting. This method is
   very inconvenient. Thanks to Rubygems 2.1.0, you now could do it
   with one command.

   **STEP - 1**

   Firstly, please make sure you upgrade your Rubygems to 2.1.0 or
   newer. For this run this command (Incase you are working on an older
   version. You can check your gem version using this command any one
   of them  *gem -v* or *gem --version*)

   *gem update --system*

   *gem --version*

   **STEP - 2**

   Run this command in you terminal

   *gem uninstall --all*

   **Step - 3**

   Install gem bundles (it is not necessary I think just for
   precautions)
   *gem install bundle*

   **Step - 4**
   Install the rails on your system using this command
   *gem install rails -v `specific version you want to install`*  you can check the rails version on the official site [rails all versions](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions) 
   example :- I have installed rails 4.2.6
   version, you install as per requirement.
   *gem install rails -v 4.2.6*

   ***Step - 5***

   Finally check the version of installed rails framework application
   by Using basic command *rails -v*. It will echoed the current
   version of rails frameworks. Enjoy :)

   **References**

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-uninstall-all-ruby-gems/
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/getting_started.html

Answer (score 4):

### Step 1:

I first kept running into an error that said:

> You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory

To get permission, I became a root user with *(this is potentially dangerous for reasons beyond my current understanding)*:

```
sudo -s
```

[Credit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26077)

### Step 2:

Then, I kept running into an error that said:

> [gem] cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

This allowed me to uninstall everything:

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133988/4373927)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, there are some weird cases where gems are installed but not really installed:

This should do the trick reasonably reliably.

```
gem uninstall -Iax `gem list  | grep default | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: You might want to grep for `'default:'` instead (including the colon) since there are quite a few gems that include "default" in their name.